# Boas praticas Orientação a Objetos

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Tenho uma classe chamada clientes. Possuo 2 métodos chamados `verificaCPF()` e `queryInsert()`.

Ambos os métodos quando faz a instrução ele da um `return` (está funcionando normal). A minha pergunta é se essa forma que estou fazendo é uma boa prática? Vocês fazem assim?
Podem me dar uma dica de melhorar essa parte de retorno da instrução?

Muito obrigado ;)

```
 public function verificaCPF($cpf) {
    try {
        $this->cpf = $cpf;
        $stmt = $this->conn->conexao()->prepare("SELECT cli_cpf FROM clientes WHERE cli_cpf =:cli_cpf");
        $stmt->bindParam(":cli_cpf", $this->cpf);
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt->rowCount() <=0){
            return 'ok'; //ALGUMA DICA PRA SER MAIS LEGIVEL PRA QUEM TA DE FORA?
        }else{
            return 'nao';
        }

    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
```

index.php

```
if (isset($_POST['cadCliente'])) {
$objCli = new clientes();

if($objCli->verificaCPF($_POST['cpf']) =='nao'){
    echo '<script>alert("CPF EM DUPLICIDADE");</script>';
}else{
    if ($objCli->queryInsert($_POST) == 'ok') {
    echo '<script>alert("Cadastro realizado!");</script>';
}
}
```

Comment: Não era mais fácil retornar `true` ou `false`, jovem? Retornar uma "string solta" é uma péssima ideia. O máximo que eu faria diferente nesse caso seria retornar constantes pré-definidas com valores numéricos, porém apenas se fosse o caso da resposta retornar algo mais além que verdadeiro ou falso

Comment: Neste caso, para quem "esta de fora", não seria mais correto chamar essa função de verificaDuplicidadeCPF. Porque verificaCPF, a primeria coisa que me vem à mente é que esta função serve para verificar se o CPF esta correto (validação do digito verificador, por exemplo)

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade sempre uso verbos sem conjugação: "verificar". Mas é exatamente o que citei no final da minha resposta e concordo com você: O método precisa descrever exatamente o que ele vai fazer.

Comment: As vezes descrever demais também me mata de raiva, kkkkk. É como você ter um método `excluirUsuario` dentro da classe `Usuario`. Eu acho que é sempre mais questão de bom-senso, de tentar sempre ser claro.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters você tem razão. Eu também só uso o infinitivo para métodos e funções.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eu detesto ouvir a palavra "boa prática" como se fosse um padrão a ser seguido a risca. Tem horas que cada caso é um caso.

Mas no seu caso específico, não seria complicar demais retornar uma `string` apenas para retornar um status em um método?

No seu caso, há duas respostas possíveis: 'ok' e 'nao'. Já é assim, porque não retornar "verdadeiro ou falso". Não seria mais fácil retornar um tipo booleano (`true` ou `false`)?

Sendo assim, não se trata nem de "boas práticas", e sim de bom senso.

Quer ver se a condição é verdadeira ou falsa? Retorne o booleano.

Além disso, não trate a `exception` dentro da chamada de um método imprimindo com um `echo`. Deixe para tratar a exceção na chamada externa. É o que eu faria nesse caso.

Inclusive, se não me falha a memória, é uma recomendação da `PSR`, separar saída de dados de retorno de dados.

Eu mudaria o método para a seguitne forma:

```
/**
* @throws PDOException
* @param string $cpf
* @return boolean
*/
public function verificaCPF($cpf) {

    $this->cpf = $cpf;
    $stmt = $this->conn->conexao()->prepare("SELECT cli_cpf FROM clientes WHERE cli_cpf =:cli_cpf");
    $stmt->bindParam(":cli_cpf", $this->cpf);
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->rowCount() > 0;

}
```

Note que eu simplesmente retornei `$stmt->rowCount() > 0`. Isso significa que estou retornando um tipo booleano. Ele retornará `true` sempre que `rowCount()` for maior que 0.

Aí, é só tratar as coisas de maneira simples e clara:

```
if (isset($_POST['cadCliente'])) {

    $objCli = new clientes();


    try{

        if (! $objCli->verificaCPF($_POST['cpf']) ){

            echo '<script>alert("CPF EM DUPLICIDADE");</script>';

        } else {

            echo '<script>alert("Cadastro realizado!");</script>';
        }


    } catch (\Exception $e) {

        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

E por fim, talvez não por questão de padrões, mas por questão de bom-senso, eu renomearia o método `verificarCpf`, pois ele não deixa claro que ele verifica se um `CPF` está duplicado. Talvez um `verificarCpfDuplicado` caiba, mas isso vai de você.

Tente sempre deixar o seu código o mais claro possível. O que eu faço é sempre imaginar que uma pessoa vai ver meu código e que ela precisa entendê-lo sem ter que ficar lendo comentários.

Comment: perfeito a resposta. não sei onde tava com a cabeça que não pensei no booleano. Obrigado pela ajuda! =)